# Javascript: when one variable is true, set all other variable to false

Tags: javascript, boolean

Is it possible to group together variables, so that when one is true the others return false?

For example: I have three variables, red, green, and blue. Initially red is `true` while blue/green are `false`, but when the user presses the spacebar, green becomes `true`. At that point, I want red to become `false`. If the user were to then press the tab key, blue would become `true` and red/green would be `false`.

Apologies if this is a really basic question that I should be able to find using Google. I've tried snooping around SO, but I didn't have any luck. Any help or ideas for how to approach this problem are appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried anything that would accomplish what I asked. So far, I've been creating variables and setting them as true/false manually in response to key events, which has gotten messy and hard to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could create an object that works like that, for instance:

```
var color = (function() {
    // set a default here
    var state = { red: true, green: false, blue: false };
    return {
        toggle: function(color) {
            Object.keys(state).forEach(function(k) {
                state[k] = (k == color) ? true : false;
            });
        },
        state: function() { 
            Object.keys(state).forEach(function(k) {
                console.log("[color] %s: %o", k, state[k]); 
            });
        }
    }
})();

color.toggle('red');
color.state();
color.toggle('green');
color.state();
color.toggle('blue');
color.state();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are different way to approximate it depending on what you're trying to do.

Why not have just one variable called `color` or something and set its value to `"red"` or `"green"` or whatever instead? If you are having the user select something from a dropdown or radio buttons this might be the simplest way to go.